# Python Multiprocessing for DataFrame Operations/Functions

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am processing 100,000s of rows of text data using Pandas Dataframes. Every so often (<5 per 100,000) I have an error for a row that I have chosen to drop. The error handling function is as follows:

```py
def unicodeHandle(datai):
    for i, row in enumerate(datai['LDTEXT']):
        print(i)
        #print(text)
        try:
            text = row.read()
            text.strip().split('[\W_]+') 
            print(text)
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            datai.drop(i, inplace=True)
            print('Error at index {}: {!r}'.format(i, row))
            print(e)
    return datai
```

The function works fine, and I have been using it a few weeks.

The problem is that I never know when the error will occur as the data comes from a DB that is constantly being added to (or I may pull different data). Point being, I must iterate through every row to run my error test function `unicodeHandle` in order initialize my data. This process takes about ~5 minutes which gets a little annoying. I am trying to implement multiprocessing to speed up the loop. Via the web and various tutorials, I have come up with:

```py
def unicodeMP(datai):
    chunks = [datai[i::8] for i in range(8)]
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
    results = pool.apply_async(unicodeHandle, chunks)
    while not results.ready():
        print("One Sec")
    return results.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fast = unicodeMP(datai)
```

When I run it the multiprocessing, it takes the same amount of time as regular even through my CPU says it is running at a WAY higher utilization. In addition, the code returns the error as a normal error instead of my completed clean dataframe. What am I missing here?

How can I use multiprocessing for functions on DataFrames?

Answer (score 1):

You can try dask for multiprocessing a dataframe

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

partitions = 7 # cpu_cores - 1
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=partitions)
ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply(unicodeHandle).compute(scheduler='processes')
```

You can read more about `dask` [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/speeding-up-your-algorithms-part-4-dask-7c6ed79994ef)

Comment: I'll have to look into this a little more before I can accept, but like the idea.

Comment: of course, you should always do that, accepting is basically an end stating you got everything you came here for