# Dask with Oracle (cx_Oracle) DatabaseError: DPI-1062: unexpected OCI return value

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, dask, cx-oracle

I am trying to use Dask to speed up a function passed over a DataFrame - more specific information on exactly what I am doing can be found here: [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584238/python-multiprocessing-for-dataframe-operations-functions).

Either way, I am using cx_Oracle to grab data into Python, and I have never had any problems with cx_Oracle. My function and Dask `.compute()` are:

```py
def unicodeHandle(datai):
    for i, row in enumerate(datai['LDTEXT']):
        print(i)
        try:
            text = row.read()
            text.strip().split('[\W_]+') 
            print(text)
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            datai.drop(i, inplace=True)
            print('Error at index {}: {!r}'.format(i, row))
            print(e)
    return datai

partitions = 7 # cpu_cores - 1
ddf = dd.from_pandas(datai, npartitions=partitions)
print(ddf)
dask = ddf.map_partitions(lambda ddf: unicodeHandle(ddf), meta=pd.DataFrame).compute()
```

`ddf` looks as it should. However, when I run `dask = ddf.map_partitions` I get:

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-f8c37d88e1f6>", line 7, in unicodeHandle
    text = row.read()

DatabaseError: DPI-1062: unexpected OCI return value 99 in function dpiLob_readBytes
```

There is nothing out on the web about this error. Does anyone what causes this error? Or, is there any documentation out there? The most I've found is the actual line of code on Github.

It only started when I started trying implement Dask, but it seems to be more of a DB error than a Dask error.

Comment: What Oracle client and DB versions are you using?  What are the [client and DB character sets](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/globalization.html#finding-the-database-and-client-character-set)? If you can find a similar example that uses pure cx_Oracle calls, then open a [cx_Oracle issue](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues).

Comment: Some small dask notes:
- You already have a defined function so you don't need the lambda.   ddf.map_partitions(unicodeHandle...)
- meta needs type info of the dataframe columns. You can get do this manually or with `dask.dataframe.utils.make_meta` -- meta=make_meta(ddf)